# laravel array to string conversion (implode doesn't work)

Tags: laravel

hi guys i'm having trouble with this update function in laravel (i'm not using the relationship (hasmany belongto ) laravel's uses since it's my learning project and it didn't work i used sql statement, the error is on the $menu_id line

```
    public function update($session,$date, Request $request)
{
 /*
   * */ //fetch the new plats edited
    $titles = $request->input('plats');

    //        fetch the menu id
     $menu_id=$this->menu->menuid($session,$date);

      //$id=implode("",$menu_id);
     //dd($id);
    foreach ($titles as $ds) {
       $plats_id=$this->menu->getplatsid($ds);

        DB::update("UPDATE Menu_items 
                               SET id_plats='$plats_id'
                                where id_menu= '".$menu_id."'  ");




    }
```

i tried the implode function but it gave me a stdclass error 
thank you

```
  public function menuid($session,$date){
    return DB::select(DB::raw("Select id 
                             from Menu 
                             where session LIKE '".$session."' AND  date ='".$date."'"));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using laravel's DB wrapper, a `SELECT` query will return a collection(`Illuminate\Support\Collection`) class. Hence the 'object' error.

Change

**From:**

`$menu_id=$this->menu->menuid($session,$date);`

**To:**

`$menu_id=$this->menu->menuid($session,$date)->implode('id');`

The `implode` function of the collection class mimics that of PHP.

Read more on [collections here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections)

The small quirks of laravel will seem troublesome at first, but given enough experience, it will speed up your development projects.

Comment: thank you for your answer 
i dd($menu_id) and this time i got ''Call to a member function implode() on a non-object"

Comment: Can you please include the function `$this->menu->menuid($session,$date)` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> i tried the implode function but it gave me a stdclass error thank you

That means that the thing you're trying to implode is an object. If you want to use the implode function you need to have an array.

To fix this, convert `$menu_id` to an array.

You can try using the `toArray` method. Like so:

```
//        fetch the menu id
$menu_id=$this->menu->menuid($session,$date)->toArray();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still get "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" (as you can se from the commented code i tried to implode but it gave this exact same error )

Comment: Can you post what you get when you `dd($menu_id)`

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => {#181 ▼
    +"id": 1
  }
]
this using your methode

Comment: i tried dumb stuff like $id=$menu_id[0] but it gives me the same error i had at first (array to string problem )

Comment: Try using the `toArray()` method, like so: `$menu_id=$this->menu->menuid($session,$date)->toArray();`

Comment: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object